# Adding a row that is writable in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have made a table that can add a row. But I want the row to be writable. When the user clicks the `addRow` a new row will appear and the user can input a text on it. Can someone help me to do it? Thankyou so much.

the code is in the jsFiddle.
[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gsz0p2pm/)

Comment: Define “writable” and “input”. Most importantly in practice, what do you intend to *do* with the user-provided data? You can add just `row.contentEditable = true` to make the content editable by the user, but what then?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution in jsFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/96oqxz9z/

All you need to add is a simple line:

```
$('#tbl1').append("<TR><TD></TD><TD><input type=\"text\"></TD></TR>");
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

[Check here](http://jsfiddle.net/gsz0p2pm/1/)

```
function addRow() {

    $('#addmore').append('<tr><td><input type="text" value="1"></td><td><input type="text" value="2"></td></tr><tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>')


};
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).on('click', '#add', function() {
  var row = '<tr><td><input type="text" /></td></tr>';
  $(this).closest('table').append(row);
})
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="add">add row </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

**try using this:**

```js
  function addRow() {
   "use strict";

    var table = document.getElementById("tbl1");
    
     var row=table.insertRow(table.rows.length);
    console.log(row);
    var td1=row.insertCell(0);
    var td11 = document.createElement("span");
    td1.appendChild(td11);

    var td2=row.insertCell(1);;
    var td22 = document.createElement("input");
    td22.type = "text";
    td2.appendChild(td22);
    td11.innerHTML = document.getElementById("a").innerHTML;
    td2.value  = document.getElementById("b").innerHTML;

    row.appendChild(td1);
    row.appendChild(td2);

    table.children[0].appendChild(row);
}
```

```html
<input type="button" onclick="addRow()" value="Add Row"/>

<TABLE id="tbl1">
     <TR>
      <TH></TH>
      <TH id="a">Principal Name</TH>
      <TH id="b">Principal Titles</TH>
     </TR>
     <TR>
      <TD></TD>
      <TD>Director Of Manager</TD>
     </TR>
     <TR>
      <TD></TD>
      <TD>President</TD>
     </TR>
     <TR>
      <TD></TD>
      <TD>Treasurer</TD>
     </TR>

    </TABLE>
```